# Stop dropdown autocomplete in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a Contact 7 form in wordpress page, which is taking last filled inputs automatically when the form is opened again, this applies to the dropdowns also.

Now in my case, I have a dropdown which loads the data automatically (that is the issue) as when my dropdown selected value is changed, it has a event handler which process few other tasks. When the event is called after the page is loaded using `.ready()` handler, the it is showing the first index. But after that, the selected index is retaining to previously selected value (value during the form was previously submitted).

I have no idea how this is happening because the event trigger is not working. But when I change the dropdown manually, it is working.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){
    $j("select").val("Can you fix this?");
    $j( "select" )
      .change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $j( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          str += $j(this).text() + " ";
        });
        alert(str.substring(5)); //the str mysteriously prefixes with 'Menu ' so I did this.
      })
      .change();
});
```

So when the page loads, I am getting the 0th index of the dropdown `<select>`. But after that, as I said, the value saved during the last form save is retained without the event being triggered.

My select short code `[select* question-201 "Can you fix this?" "How much do repairs cost?" "Did you receive my order?" "When will my order be ready?" "Other"]`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the cookie which is set by the form. The cookie name will be `inbound_<field name>`. In this case it is `inbound_question-201`.

As a temporary workaround, this cookie can be deleted before the autocomplete script starts working. So, change the javascript code as

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){
    document.cookie = "inbound_question-201=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/"; //this is the trick
    $j( "select" )
      .change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $j( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          str += $j(this).text() + " ";
        });
        alert(str.substring(5));
      })
      .change();
});
```